# More efficiently write if statements

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int Age ;


int main(){
    cout << "How old are you? ";
    cin >> Age;


    if (Age < 1)
    { 

    cout << "I dont believe you!";
    }

if (Age == 20)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}
if (Age == 21)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}
if (Age == 22)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}
if (Age == 23)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}
if (Age == 24)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}
if (Age == 25)
{
    cout << "We're almost the same age!" << endl;
}

if ( Age % 2 == 1)
{
cout << "Thats an odd age.";
}
cout << "";
}
```

Instead of having so many if statements is there any way to more efficently write a program that checks if the users age is between 20-25?

I myself tried using or's in between the conditions for each number like so

```
if (Age ==20||21||22||23||24||25)
```

but that did not work

Comment: `if (Age >=20 && Age <= 25)` ?

Comment: For your approach to work you would need: `if (Age==20||Age==21||Age==22||Age==23||Age==24||Age=25){}`, but the range checks in the answers are better.

Comment: Type i then f. I you get them backward you'll have to start again. Very inefficient. But seriously, for something like `if (Age ==20||21||22||23||24||25)` consider a `switch` statement.

Comment: Have you read up on the workings of boolean expressions in C++.   If not, given what you are trying to do, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (Age >= 20 && Age <= 25) {
    // write your code here
}
```

The boolean expression in the if statement means, `Age` should be `greater that or equal to` 20 **and** `less than or equal to` 25. For example, `22 is greater than 20 and less than 25`.

I suggest you to read about [logical operators in C++](http://www.c4learn.com/cplusplus/cpp-logical-operator/).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((Age >= 20) && (Age <= 25))
```

Answer (score 1):

Between:

```
if (Age > 20 && Age < 25)
```

Including both limits:

```
if (Age >=20 && Age <=25)
```

Off topic: use switch case

```
switch (Age) {
case 20:
case 21:
case 22:
case 23:
case 24:
case 25:
    cout << "We're almost the same age\n";
    break;
// other cases
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch). Or perhaps consider some [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) mapping numbers to [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (e.g. a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)`<int,std::function<void(int)>`....), initialize it and access it to get what handling should be done.

You need to read a lot more about programming (e.g. [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) and about [C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/).

Spend several weeks in reading stuff. Read also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight about learning programming.